# the value of second byte of a single variable

Tags: c, vb.net

hi guys
I have a variable  as a single.
how can I found out that, what is the value of second byte of my variable.
or  what is the value of third byte of my variable value in memory.?
in c language we use at like this `*(char(&x)+1)`
which method do the same thing in vb.net

thnx

Comment: Note: In C, we use `*((char *)&x + 1)`.  Then we worry about the fact that this isn't platform-independent.

Answer (score 1):

Use BitConverter.GetBytes():

```
    Dim value As Single = 1.23!
    Dim secondByte = BitConverter.GetBytes(value)(1)
```